# Edit Context Menu of Specific File Extension, and Exclude Entries From the * (All Files) Context Menu

Tags: windows, windows-8, context-menu, file-extension

I would like to create an entirely unique context menu for a specific file type.  I have added all the items I'd like to add to the context menu, but I don't know how to remove existing ones.  I'd like to remove entries like "Cut," "Copy," etc., if possible.  I don't, however, want to change the context menu items for * (all files).

Comment: Use http://defaultprogramseditor.com/#download  to edit entries  
Use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shmnview-x64.zip to view and disable entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. *Cut* & *Copy* are part of Windows shell.